# Adding IcedCoffeeScript keywords to Webstorm Intellisense

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm, iced-coffeescript

I want to add a few IcedCoffeeScript keywords to the CoffeeScript files highlighting, but the edit button is grayed out for the CoffeeScript file type.  Is there a way that I could duplicate a file type that's already in the list and add keywords?   Or, is there a simple way to add keywords to an existing filetype?  Why is edit file type grayed out for CoffeeScript files but not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No -- you cannot extend existing language by adding your own keywords, as original support is done via Java-based plugin (for proper language support: syntax, inspections, validations, code completions, refactorings etc).

Actual ticket on JetBrains Issue Tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11996